# Get all combinations of element from a list, including all different orders & writing it in 2 different ways

Tags: python, combinations

I have already found the question to get all possible combinations given a list, but not how to get as well all possible orders. Additionally, I am looking also for another way to output the combinations.

For example, let's say I have following list of elements:

```
['A', 'B', 'C']
```

I would like to generate a dictionary matching these 2 ways the combinations can be expressed.

The 1st one is through lists of variable length to express the different combinations and different orders:

```
[]
['A']
['A','B']
['B','A']
...
['A','B','C']
['A','C','B']
['C','A','B']
...
```

The 2nd is using fixed-size lists where positive integers indicate in reverse order the position of said element (first element starts at 0, then second element is 1, third element is 2, and so on...), and replacing 'void' element ('') with -1.
This gives:

```
#     Initial list: [ 'A', 'B', 'C'] 
                       |    |    |
                       v    v    v
[]             ->   [ -1 , -1 , -1 ] 
['A']          ->   [  0 , -1 , -1 ]
['A','B']      ->   [  0 ,  1 , -1 ]
['B','A']      ->   [  1 ,  0 , -1 ]
...
['A','B','C']  ->   [  0 ,  1 ,  2 ]
['A','C','B']  ->   [  0 ,  2 ,  1 ]
['C','A','B']  ->   [  1 ,  2 ,  0 ]
...
```

---

**Solution based on @match 's proposal**

```
data = ['A', 'B', 'C']
result = list(chain.from_iterable([permutations(data, x) for x in range(len(data)+1)]))

numbers = []
for item in result:
    new_list = [-1, -1, -1]
    for entry in item:
        idx = data.index(entry)
        new_list[idx] = item.index(entry)
    numbers.append(new_list)

print(numbers)

[[-1, -1, -1], [0, -1, -1], [-1, 0, -1], [-1, -1, 0], [0, 1, -1], [0, -1, 1], [1, 0, -1], [-1, 0, 1], [1, -1, 0], [-1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 2], [0, 2, 1], [1, 0, 2], [2, 0, 1], [1, 2, 0], [2, 1, 0]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `itertools.permutations` to build up a list of lists containing all the combinations of the items for all the possible 'lengths' as follows (the extra `list(chain.from_iterable(...))` is just there to flatten things down a level:

```
from itertools import chain, permutations

data = ['A', 'B', 'C']
result = list(chain.from_iterable([permutations(data, x) for x in range(len(data)+1)]))
```

`[(), ('A',), ('B',), ('C',), ('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('B', 'A'), ('B', 'C'), ('C', 'A'), ('C', 'B'), ('A', 'B', 'C'), ('A', 'C', 'B'), ('B', 'A', 'C'), ('B', 'C', 'A'), ('C', 'A', 'B'), ('C', 'B', 'A')]`

To map this onto numerical positions, you can use `data.index(string) to find its position. I'm not 100% if this is what you mean, but something like the following should get you there...

```
numbers = []
for item in result:
    new_list = []
    for entry in item:
        # Fill the new list with the index of each letter seen.
        new_list.append(data.index(entry))
    # Pad out the rest of the list with -1
    new_list += [-1] * (len(data) - len(new_list))
    numbers.append(new_list)

print(numbers)
```

`[[-1, -1, -1], [0, -1, -1], [1, -1, -1], [2, -1, -1], [0, 1, -1], [0, 2, -1], [1, 0, -1], [1, 2, -1], [2, 0, -1], [2, 1, -1], [0, 1, 2], [0, 2, 1], [1, 0, 2], [1, 2, 0], [2, 0, 1], [2, 1, 0]]`

Comment: Hi @match, thanks for your input. Hmm regarding the mapping to numerical positions, your proposal does not seem to do exactly the job. Looking at the 3rd list: [1, -1, -1] This combination is not possible, if there are positive numbers, they should start at 0. If there are 2 positive numbers, it should be `0` and `1`. And if there are 3 of them, it should then be `0`, `1`, `2`.

Comment: ok, got it, built on your proposal. I am editing my post to write the correct answer for numerical positions. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

How about

```py
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement 

my_list = ['A', 'B', 'C']
combinations_with_replacement(my_list, 1)
combinations_with_replacement(my_list, 2)
combinations_with_replacement(my_list, 3)
```

You can then easily add the empty variant. Finally, you can then put this into a pandas data frame and replace it. If you need furhter help, just post below this post.

**EDIT**

I'm sorry, I have missread the question. Please find the correct solution with pandas below.

```py
from itertools import chain, permutations
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


my_list = ["A", "B", "C"]

my_list_permutations = list(
    chain.from_iterable(permutations(my_list, n) for n in range(len(my_list)+1)))

arr = np.full(len(my_list_permutations), -1)
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"A": arr, "B": arr, "C": arr, "Permutation": ["" for i in range(len(arr))]})


for idx, permutation in enumerate(my_list_permutations):
    try:
        for letter in permutation:
            df.loc[idx, letter] = permutation.index(letter)

        df.loc[idx, "Permutation"] = f"{permutation}"
    except KeyError as e:
        pass
```

Comment: Hi @MacOS, thanks for your help, but unless I am missing something, it does not do the job. I had a look at `combinations_with_replacement`. It does two things that I don't want: 1st/ it allows individual elements to be repeated more than once (in the example I give, you will see there is no repetition) 2nd/ it sorts values according their position, and does not issue combinations for different sorting, which I need as shown in the example. So, I don't see how it should solve the problem here.

Comment: I'm sorry. I have updated my answer.